# How to combine multiple API requests in one function with fetch() in React

Tags: reactjs, request, fetch, use-effect, use-state

I have to functions `getDataOne` and `getDataTwo`. How do I combine below into one function, using `fetch()`, `useState` and `useEffect`?

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [dataOne, setDataOne] = useState<Data[]>([]);
  const [dataTwo, setDataTwo] = useState<Data[]>([]);

  const getDataOne = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const result = await fetch(
      "https://my-api-link-one"
    );
    const jsonResult = await result.json();

    setLoading(false);
    setDataOne(jsonResult);
  };

  const getDataTwo = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const result = await fetch(
      "https://my-api-link-two"
    );
    const jsonResult = await result.json();

    setLoading(false);
    setDataTwo(jsonResult);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDataOne();
    getDataTwo();
  }, []);
```

**Update:**

I set it up using `Promise.all`

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
   const [dataOne, setDataOne] = useState<DataOne[]>([]);
   const [dataTwo, setDataTwo] = useState<DataTwo[]>([]);
   const [data, setData] = useState<DataOne[] & DataTwo>([]);

    const urls = [
        "https://url-one", "https://url-two",
      ];
    
      const getData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const results = await Promise.all(
          urls.map((url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()))
        );
    
        setLoading(false);
        setData(results);
        console.log(data);
      };
```

This is not totally working yet. How do I use `useState` now correctly (and handle both data from urls)? In the end I want to have one `data` variable so I can map over this variable:

```
{data.map((item) => {
          return (
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.all`. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all.

```
const getData = () => {
setLoading(true);
Promise.all([fetch('api-1'), fetch('api-2')]).then(results => {
 setDataOne(results[0]);
 setDataTwo(results[1]);
}).finally(() => setLoading(false));
}
```

Comment: thanks, I am close.. I updated my question. Do you know how to achieve that in a clean way?

Answer (score 1):

So, `Promise.all()` accepts an array of promises, so naturally `Promise.all()` returns an array only. So even though your `results` variable still is an array I would recommend destructuring it because in this case there are only two API fetches involved. Looking at your update, I think there's only small modifications left which are as follows :

```js
    const urls = ["https://url-one", "https://url-two",];

    const getData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all(
        urls.map((url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()))
     );
      setLoading(false);
      setDataOne(result1);
      setDataTwo(result2);
      console.log(data);
    };
```

Comment: thanks, but my last question is how do I use `useState` in this case? In my updated answer I have now 3 `useState` variables declared. Maybe that's wrong. In the end I want them into one [data, setData], so I am able to `map()` `data` like `{data.map((item) => {}`

Comment: @meez if you're expecting arrays from both the API results you can concatenate them, right? I mean something like this should work `setData([...result1, ...result2])`

Comment: Are you sure you're getting response as an array? If yes then could you please send the JSON of 2nd URL

Comment: So after Promise operation do something like this `const modifiedResults2 = result2.myItems;` Then combine like this `setData([...result1,...modifiedResults2])`. By the way is `results1` JSON like result2 or is it different?

Comment: Ok thanks, almost there. Now I get an empty array because I think I set my types not correct: `const [data, setData] = useState<TypeOne[] | TypeTwo[]>([]);`. The mapped items should contain TypeOne and or TypeTwo (results1 and results2)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `.flat()` to reformat the data array returned from the `Promise.all()` into your state which holds the response obj/array,

```
Promise.all(
    urls.map(url => 
        fetch(url).then(e => e.json())
    )
).then(data => {
    finalResultState = data.flat();
});
```